# User Unsupported Data Source: https://officeltd.gmaltd.in/d.php is not a supported raster data source

Tags: php, centos, tiff, qgis

The URL which I am providing downloading the .tif file but giving following error in QGIS:

> User Unsupported Data Source: https://officeltd.gmaltd.in/d.php is not a supported raster data source.

The contents of `d.php` file is:

```php
<?php

    $rasterPath = 'https://10.14.52.16/Careers/25143_LOGOWER_LKGMB_LMN.tif';

    if (file_exists($rasterPath)) {
    header('Content-Type: image/tiff');
    $context = stream_context_create(['ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false]]);
    readfile($rasterPath, false, $context);
    } else {
   
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    echo 'File not found.';
    }
?>
```

I want to roster .tif file in QGIS Application by providing the URL:
https://officeltd.gmaltd.in/d.php

If I am providing this URL: "https://10.14.52.16/Careers/25143_LOGOWER_LKGMB_LMN.tif" in QGIS then it rosters the image correctly.